# Zuul Gateway not carrying Authorization Header

Tags: spring-security-oauth2, netflix-zuul, spring-oauth2

I want to build zuul gateway with oauth2 sso integration with jwt. when i request zuul, it redirect to oauth2 server and i login there successfully. it returns zuul and forwards request to resource server but without authorization header. **i applied suggested solution before. (like sensitiveHeaders: Cookie,Set-Cookie,Authorization in zuul configuration)** but still not carry this authorization header.

i see jwt token in oauth2 server logs. so access_token is successfully provided.

> After request [**uri=/authorization/oauth/authorize**?client_id=first-client&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/gateway/login&response_type=code&scope=custom_mod&state=43Vu18;headers=[**authorization:"Basic Zmlyc3QtY2xpZW50Om5vb25ld2lsbGV2ZXJndWVzcw==**", cookie:"JSESSIONID=A58A2A9977B210BB2ADA40BD482B63A2; JSESSIONID=B1F8F6F27639B923EB7BF07CB44E0B87", host:"localhost:8094",
>
> After request [**uri=/authorization/oauth/token**;**headers=[authorization:"Basic Zmlyc3QtY2xpZW50Om5vb25ld2lsbGV2ZXJndWVzcw=="**, host:"localhost:8094", ];payload=grant_type=authorization_code&code=QHqLLS&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fgateway%2Flogin]
>
> After request [**uri=/authorization/userinfo**;headers=[**authorization:"Bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJleHAiOjE1ODE2Njc5NjksInVzZXJfbmFtZSI6ImRnIiwiYXV0aG9yaXRpZXMiOlsiUk9MRV9BRE1JTiJdLCJqdGkiOiI3YWI1ZGRiMC1kNzBlLTQxYTctOWI3Yy01NTVjM2I0Nzk0OGYiLCJjbGllbnRfaWQiOiJmaXJzdC1jbGllbnQiLCJzY29wZSI6WyJjdXN0b21fbW9kIl19.bUJp8Z-a9eLJQJFb8KjbSuUCWWyoeI9UWL-E9djeoYrPYmRId-dD-rV75OP5QJKwUU1zBhBUErCyFM0tlEp2K1dB0Lg8hZxouavFmPOyakO97fs1A_IFfv5XePIXYgqh-jRKCQHXPKJLisIKl9Iav4c-pz0etyjaR6fhnmiLHg50Q3SAM7vwkISZ3z3EvJChRIo--tgY6PjnFLX2E3NQhSglCJ_shb-cZ8qEn2avQzNJBMLAoOo988362ft6m8rP1Oi0BojRI4P6blxNwT1pQA7JwjcxtdeMdSVy4BhwaMgObiQfYEn0AnJDJOwffdc7DjIS62um7HpSRMM55Ty6Gg**",host:"localhost:8094"]]

but in zuul console logs, there is no authorization header in request.

> After request [GET /gateway/resource/mod, headers=cookie:"JSESSIONID=0664AD4111623C1EF35C2E1BD1CC6C55; JSESSIONID=B1F8F6F27639B923EB7BF07CB44E0B87", host:"localhost:8080", sec-fetch-mode:"navigate", sec-fetch-site:"none", sec-fetch-user:"?1", upgrade-insecure-requests:"1"]]

what i am missing, thanks for helping.

here is my zuul configuration.

```
zuul:
  sensitiveHeaders: Cookie,Set-Cookie,Authorization
  routes:
    oauth-resource:
      path: /resource/**
      url: http://localhost:8097/myresource/resource

ssoServiceUrl: http://localhost:8094/authorization

security:
  oauth2:
    client:
      client-id: first-client
      client-secret: noonewilleverguess
      access-token-uri: ${ssoServiceUrl}/oauth/token
      user-authorization-uri: ${ssoServiceUrl}/oauth/authorize
      scope: custom_mod
    resource:
      prefer-token-info: false
      user-info-uri: ${ssoServiceUrl}/userinfo
server:
  servlet:
    context-path: /gateway
```

zuul application code

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableZuulProxy
@EnableOAuth2Sso
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class DemoApplication extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();
        ;
    }

    @Bean
    public CommonsRequestLoggingFilter requestLoggingFilter() {
        CommonsRequestLoggingFilter loggingFilter = new CommonsRequestLoggingFilter();
        loggingFilter.setIncludeQueryString(true);
        loggingFilter.setIncludePayload(true);
        loggingFilter.setIncludeHeaders(true);
        return loggingFilter;
    }

}
```

Comment: i debug request by creating prefilter. in request's ingoredHeaders field, there are 9 values including cookie, set-cookie, authorization etc. i think configurations in yml file cannot be applied for a reason, but why?

Comment: when you do 'sensitiveHeaders: Cookie,Set-Cookie,Authorization' it says remove these.This is black list https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/2.0.x/single/spring-cloud-netflix.html#_cookies_and_sensitive_headers